# rangeslider.js set default min, max for range

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I am using a template and the rangeslider initialization looks like this:

```
$(".range-slider-ui").each(function () {
        var minRangeValue = $(this).attr('data-min');
        var maxRangeValue = $(this).attr('data-max');
        var currMin = $(this).attr('data-curr-min');
        var currMax = $(this).attr('data-curr-max');
        var minName = $(this).attr('data-min-name');
        var maxName = $(this).attr('data-max-name');
        var unit = $(this).attr('data-unit');

        $(this).append("" +
            "<span class='min-value'></span> " +
            "<span class='max-value'></span>" +
            "<input class='current-min' type='hidden' name='"+minName+"'>" +
            "<input class='current-max' type='hidden' name='"+maxName+"'>"
        );
        $(this).slider({
            range: true,
            min: minRangeValue,
            max: maxRangeValue,
            step: 100,
            values: [minRangeValue, maxRangeValue],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                event = event;
                var currentMin = parseInt(ui.values[0]);
                var currentMax = parseFloat(ui.values[1]);
                $(this).children(".min-value").text( currentMin + " " + unit);
                $(this).children(".max-value").text(currentMax + " " + unit);
                $(this).children(".current-min").val(currentMin);
                $(this).children(".current-max").val(currentMax);
            }
        });

        var currentMin = parseInt($(this).slider("values", 0));
        var currentMax = parseFloat($(this).slider("values", 1));
        $(this).children(".min-value").text( currentMin + " " + unit);
        $(this).children(".max-value").text(currentMax + " " + unit);
        $(this).children(".current-min").val(currentMin);
        $(this).children(".current-max").val(currentMax);

    });
```

The only thing I've added is

```
var currMin = $(this).attr('data-curr-min');
var currMax = $(this).attr('data-curr-max');
```

I'm passing the current min and max settings from the server.  These attributes have the correct values.  All I want to do is set the default min and max values.  I tried simply setting the

```
values: [currMin, currMax]
```

but this causes problems.  There has to be a simple way to do this but everything I've tried, doesn't work.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try .html() instead of .val()

```
$(this).children(".current-min").html(currentMin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I later determined it was a caching issue.  The code I posted initially does work.